# GCP Document AI patch-process-documents

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I had a recent problem with GCP document AI Patch-Process , there is a strange pattern happened yesterday , I take advantage of tables prop which extracts the tables from a document

The current behavior is this tables prop is missing from patch version , when I did check the output JSON in storage , I can't find it .

But When I tried the same document with the ordinary way not as patch , I managed to find it , its critical for me using this service as patches not as single document at a time ,

I'm using "pretrained-form-parser-v2.0-2022-11-10"

[Here is the response from Patch Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WElTN.png)

[Here is the response from Normal Form Parser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd4lz.png)

[In both versions I used the code samples listed here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-document-ai)

Thanks in advance.